# NiceTabular tables background color rendering incorrectly upon building

Tags: tables, pdftex, rendering, nicematrix

I'm pretty new to LaTeX and I'm coming up at a loss on some troubleshooting. I've been using NiceTabular from the NiceMatrix package to make tables since I've found they look the best when it comes to background color. The problem I'm having is whenever I rebuild the document using PDFLaTeX, the first time around the background color renders incorrectly (see image below). Sometimes the background color is just off the row, but sometimes it's even the wrong shape. However, if I rebuild once or twice, it will always fix itself and render correctly. I've heard of unrelated issues with builders (not just PDFLaTeX) that requires building a document more than once to get the expected outcome (I'm assuming that is why there are template Quick Builds on TeXMaker that include building more than once for certain builders). Is this just maybe one of those instances? I've also heard of issues that some packages can be affected by `\usepackage` load order. I tried moving around my packages but that did not fix it. Am I just stuck having to build two or three times via PDFLaTeX to get the expected result, or is there something I'm missing here? I'm running Windows 10 on latest MikTex and TeXMaker versions.

[image]

Packages:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=0.5in]{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\usepackage[a3paper]{geometry} % This package allows the editing of the page layout
\usepackage{amsmath}  % This package allows the use of a large range of mathematical formula, commands, and symbols
\usepackage{graphicx}  % This package allows the importing of images
\usepackage{inconsolata}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

And a sample table from the document:

```
\begin{NiceTabular}{|P{0.175}|P{0.1}|P{0.1}|P{0.625}|}[code-before = \rowcolor{tablelightgray}{1}]
    \hline
        \textbf{Variable Name} & \textbf{Class} & \textbf{Size} & \textbf{Description}\\
    \hline   
        \texttt{dur} & \texttt{double} & \texttt{nx1} & Vector of duration values with each duration value corresponding to a magnitude.\\
    \hline
        \texttt{mag} & \texttt{double} & \texttt{nx1} & Vector of magnitude values discretized between zero and the peak value of the data trace.\\
    \hline
\end{NiceTabular}
```

Comment: How did you define the `P` column type and the color `tablelightgray`?

Comment: `\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-1.5\arrayrulewidth}}` and `\definecolor{tablelightgray}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the `nicematrix` manual:

> The idea of `nicematrix` is to create `pgf` nodes under the cells and the
> positions of the rules of the tabular created by `array` and to use these
> nodes to develop new features. As usual with `pgf`, the coordinates of
> these nodes are written in the `.aux` to be used on the next compilation
> and that’s why `nicematrix` may need **several** compilations.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know. Made a new quick build in TeXMaker to build several times so I don't have to worry about it anymore!